# Sharepoint 2010  GlobalNavigation

Tags: navigation

I have a request for a client who has three level of navigation and would like to use the global navigation to set the navigation links in site site settings>navigation.(/_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx)

Is that doable?

Thanks in advance for your reply :)
Will

- 1st level navigation

  - 2nd level navigation

    - 3rd level navigation

so for the navigation we would have something like that:

- Company (1st level navigation)

  - About us (2nd level navigation)

    - Contact us (3rd level navigation)
    - Team (3rd level navigation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atos, there are 2 different ways depending upon whether you want it dynamically-managed by SharePoint or created/managed by the Farm Administrator.

Dynamically-managed is by adjusting the [Master Pages MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels tag](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/5fc51414-198c-47c6-871e-945dbbcaad8f/).

The managed version, which adds your own [custom links with as many levels as you want](http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/07/sharepoint-2010-two-tier-global.html), but requires an administrator to change a custom XML file, solves this too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that sounds like it could work for a custom navigation but in my case my client need to be able to change the navigation from Site Settings : Navigation Settings (_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx)